# Query with json output on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have this query

```
select
json_build_object(
    'categories', json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'catID',c.category_id,
            'cat_name', c.fr,
            'cat_prior', c.priority,
            'links', links
        )
    )
) categories FROM category c left join (
select json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'linkID', l.link_id,
            'link_name', l.label,
            'link_address', l.address
            )
        )  links
FROM link l) l on c.category_id @> l.cats GROUP BY c.category_id;
```

I have this error : column l.cats does not exist.
My table category

```
category_id     integer     
slug    character varying(255)  
fr  character varying(25)   
priority    integer
```

My table link

```
link_id     bigint
label   character varying(50)   
address     text    
cats    integer[]   
priority    integer
```

I use Intarray module.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a column called `cats` for the alias `l`.  There is exactly one column, `links`.  The error is obvious.

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Oh yes thank you, I was confused with so many levels.